# Wallpaper app, dont work image gallery saver

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a wallpaper application, I ran into this problem 1) For some reason, the image gallery saver does not work, the resolution works 2) If someone understands infinity scroll I will be very happy to help, I just can’t write it into the code.  Thanks in advance for the answers
https://github.com/Myliu1904/New_Wallpaper_HD/blob/master/lib/views/imageView.dart
https://github.com/Myliu1904/New_Wallpaper_HD/blob/master/lib/controller/imageView_controller.dart

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you talk about in first question, but for the `long Lists` you can read this doc from flutter https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists.

Comment: I'm talking about the pub plugin image gallary saver, so for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/Myliu1904/Wallpaper_HD/blob/master/lib/views/imageView.dart 
Here

Comment: I am really sorry for not been able to help you.